# ng-click inside ag-grid header template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have defined template for header:

```
  headerCellTemplate: function () {
            var eCell = document.createElement('span');
            eCell.innerHTML = '<span ng-click="deleteColumn()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></button></span>';
            return eCell;
        }
```

And I also have function in my controller:

```
$scope.deleteColumn = new function(){
    console.log("test");
}
```

How can I make ag-grid to invoke deleteColumn() from my $scope? Because now clicking is not invoking method from parent scope.

Comment: You have to compile the template. Something like $compile(cellHtml)($scope)

Comment: @x-act Should I compile it in headerCellTemplate function? Or should I get this html from jquery and then $compile?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, angular compiling in headerTemplates is not supported. You'll have to use a headerCellRenderer.

This should work:

```
headerCellRendererFunc: function (params) {
    // set the right scope for the grid params
    params.$scope.deleteColumn = $scope.deleteColumn;

    var eCell = document.createElement('span');
    eCell.innerHTML = '<span ng-click="deleteColumn()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></button></span>';
    return eCell;
}
```

Also make sure you have angular-compiling for headers in your gridOptions enabled:

```
$scope.gridOptions =
{
    ...
    headerCellRenderer: headerCellRendererFunc,
    angularCompileHeaders: true,
    ...
}
```